# JupyterLab has long launch delay. Caused by any extension?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

My JupyterLab has a long launch delay. It takes ~ 20 seconds

**from** reading config json files

```
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]: [D 2023-01-25 22:37:53.492 ServerApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_server_config:
```

**to** extension linkage

```
Jan 25 22:38:11 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]: [I 2023-01-25 22:38:11.816 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
```

Detailed logs are here:

```
Jan 25 22:37:41 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 systemd[1]: Started Jupyter Notebook Service.
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]: [D 2023-01-25 22:37:53.492 ServerApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_server_config:
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]:             /etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.json
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]: [D 2023-01-25 22:37:53.493 ServerApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_server_config:
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]:             /usr/local/etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.json
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]: [D 2023-01-25 22:37:53.493 ServerApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_server_config:
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]:             /opt/conda/etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.d/beatrix_jupyterlab.json
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]:             /opt/conda/etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.d/jupyter-server-proxy-jupyterserverexten>
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]:             /opt/conda/etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.d/jupyter_server_mathjax.json
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]:             /opt/conda/etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.d/jupyterlab.json
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]:             /opt/conda/etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.d/jupyterlab_git.json
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]:             /opt/conda/etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.d/jupytext.json
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]:             /opt/conda/etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.d/nbclassic.json
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]:             /opt/conda/etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.d/nbdime.json
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]:             /opt/conda/etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.d/notebook_shim.json
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]:             /opt/conda/etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.json
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]: [D 2023-01-25 22:37:53.619 ServerApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_server_config:
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]:             /home/jupyter/.local/etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config.json
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]: [D 2023-01-25 22:37:53.619 ServerApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_server_config:
Jan 25 22:37:53 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]:             /home/jupyter/.jupyter/jupyter_server_config.json
Jan 25 22:38:07 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]: Matplotlib is building the font cache; this may take a moment.
Jan 25 22:38:11 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]: [I 2023-01-25 22:38:11.816 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
Jan 25 22:38:11 xinliupitt-prebuilt-20 bash[1625]: [I 2023-01-25 22:38:11.816 ServerApp] jupyterlab_git | extension was successfully linked.
.
.
.
```

I tried to disable extensions one by one and see which one is the root cause of the delay. For example, I disabled extensions: "jupyter_server_mathjax", "jupyterlab", "jupyterlab_git", etc.

I can disable all extensions successfully (and found they are not root causes) except the "jupyterlab" extension. To disable "jupyterlab" extension, I tried these approaches

- modify the content of jupyterlab.json from true to false
- delete jupyterlab.json
- before jupyter launch stage, use cmd `jupyter labextension disable jupyterlab`
- try any of jupyter launch cmd below

```
        jupyter lab --dev-mode            # start JupyterLab in development mode, with no extensions
        jupyter lab --core-mode           # start JupyterLab in core mode, with no extensions
        jupyter lab --app-dir=~/myjupyterlabapp # start JupyterLab with a particular set of extensions
```

However, none of them successfully disabled "jupyterlab" extension, since finally this log always appears

```
jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
```

I also tried if `"buildCheck": false` can disable the extensions.

- [page_config.json](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/7381)
- [jupyter_notebook_config.json](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.x/user/extensions.html#disabling-rebuild-checks)
- [jupyter_config.json](https://github.com/deathbeds/ipydrawio/blob/master/atest/fixtures/jupyter_config.json#L6)

No it didn't work; the log still shows "extension was successfully linked."

## My questions:

1. Has anyone experienced JupyterLab long launch delay and how did you resolve it?
2. Is there any other approach for me to disable the "jupyterlab" extension?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You cannot run jupyterlab without jupyterlab server extension. It does not make sense. Did you try running with `--debug` flag to see what happens in between the two actions?

Comment: Thanks for your great tip! I ran `jupyter lab --debug`. Then, I got extra logs like "Looking for jupyter_config in /opt/conda/etc/jupyter" with the same timestamp as "Paths used for configuration". The extra logs don't add useful info.    Do you have other tips to further reveal the hidden process?

Comment: I see this conversation is also happening on gitter - please post back anything useful here later so that it is out there in the open, searching gitter is difficult.

Comment: So https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter_server/pull/1171 added logging on `info` level which prints out how long import of specific extensions took. This was released in jupyter-server 2.1 so if you can upgrade, this could give you some more info.

Comment: Also it looks like https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter_server/pull/1180 will help too, but this one was not released yet (but is already merged).

Comment: @krassowski both comments are very useful, we will upgrade and report back thanks

Comment: @krassowski Per tips from gitter, I tried `python3 -c "import matplotlib.pyplot"` before jupyter launching. Then during Jupyter launching, the log "Matplotlib is building..." disappear and its corresponding delay is reduced.

Comment: @krassowski Jupeter-server 2.2.0 is [released](https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter_server/releases/tag/v2.2.0), involving the fix in issue#8080. I will try it